# Use embedded images in FlexLib Project in Actionscript Project

Tags: apache-flex, image, actionscript, embed

I have a **FlexLib Project** with a embed class:

```
package
{

    public class EmbedAssets
    {
        [Embed( source="image.png" )]
        public static var IMAGE:Class;
    }
}
```

At the same project, I have a class that use this embedded image:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Visual extends Sprite
    {
        public function Visual()
        {
            super();

            var aa:DisplayObject = new EmbedAssets.IMAGE() as DisplayObject;

            addChild( aa );
        }
    }
}
```

And I have another **Actionscript Project** that use this **FlexLib Project** and add the **Visual** class on stage:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class AsTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function AsTest()
        {
            addChild( new Visual());
        }
    }
}
```

The image don't show up, just.

I had debug the application and found the bitmapData of aa was NULL. But if I implement out of Lib Project, this work!

In properties of projects ai tried a lot configurations on Flex Library Build Path -> Classes / Assets. But none work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Idemax Green (question author) discovered that it works ok with prev SDK's but not with Flex SDK Hero - Beta - 4.5.0.17689, he logged it as a bug: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-29135

If the FlexLib project is merged with your application code, then i'm pretty sure it will not see the image at that location at runtime, as the location will be different e.g. the library will be in the **libs** folder of the main app. Check where the FlexLib swc is located in you bin-debug folder, and maybe modify the path in EmbedAssets to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for help. But it isn't a problem. The FlexLib and AS Project are two totally separate projects and all other things are ok, like path of SWC file and classes. The problem is bitmapData property of DisplayObject variable be NULL. If you try it without lib projects, this will work!

Comment: As a library project, are you using it as an RSL or a Merged library when its deployed? How could you try it without the library project?

Comment: At FlexLib Project in Properties -> Flex Library Build Path -> Library path Tab, the Framework linkage is "Use default (external)". And at Actionscript Project in Properties -> Actionscript Build Path -> Library path Tab, the Framework linkage is "Use default (merged into code)" with "Verify RSL digests (recommended for production)" checked at bottom. Is it the problem?

Comment: I just created the exact same projects as you, and it worked fine. I placed the image in the src folder of the FlexLib proj with the Visual and EmbededAssets classes. Make sure to Project>Clean on you FlexLib project, and in the Main app go to Properties>Build Path>Library and click 'Add SWC', point it to the FlexLib.swc in the bin folder of the FlexLib project.

Comment: Brian, what SDK are you using? I'm using the 4.5 Hero. Please, send me the your two projects to test myself. My e-mail is idemax@gmail.com.

Comment: I reported as a bug because happens only with Flex Hero SDK: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-29135

Comment: Answers of Gaurav Jain from Adobe: "This is already fixed in the latest hero builds. I tested using 19777", and: "The nightly build for the hero release are *not* yet public. See the build section under http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Hero". So we have to wait... =(

Answer (score 0):

You should add the library project's assets directory to the application project's source path.

If you are using FlashBuilder, you should edit the flex application's .project file, and extend the `linkedResources` tag as follows:

```
<linkedResources>
    [...]
    <link>
        <name>[source path] assets</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>YOUR_WORKSPACE/YourFlexLib/src/assets</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

Comment: Did you tested this using the 4.5 Hero SDK?

Comment: please make sure that all these new <link /> tags point to valid locations, and also -if using more library projects- to add all the locations you use (just like in locales) to the source path.